# Spring security how to allow root url without intefering with security 'below' the root

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have REST services and static pages, both delivered by my Spring Boot application.

The application action is to be reached under /myapp, while under /myapp/api there are services that are protected by a filter.
The filter expects a cookie.

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new CookieFilter(...));
}
```

The unprotected pages in the 'root-context (/myapp) have no cookie.

How can I configure that the static pages are 'ignored' by Spring security?  While the REST endpoints below the static pages are checked by security?

When I try to configure the static pages for 'exclusion' via Web Security, all REST endpoints under /myapp/api are ignored as well

```
@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
   web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/");
}
```

If I configure a permitAll():

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new CookieFilter(...));

}
```

Spring security complains that the static pages can not be checked by my security filter, so the authorization is performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make anything under /api require authentication and let everything else through.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new CookieFilter(...));
```

Comment: OK, thank You, I also added a '/*' to the 'WebSecurity ignore list' so that the static content in the rot directory will be delivered.